# Float is not returning correct value

Tags: c++, glut

Just a quick heads-up there may be more things wrong than just with my code as I am still learning how to correctly post questions.

I am developing my first program, which has a purpose. I have followed many tutorials and have a basic understanding of programming.

I am using VC++ 2012 and glut openGL version 4.3.0

My goal was to input a number corresponding to a weather. Then depending on the number a different animation would play. To simplify things at first, I was just going to change the background colour.

I discovered that this was done with this.

```
glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
```

Which seemed to work when manually entering the numbers via the code. However when I tried to assign each RGB value with a float in a different class, the resulting background stayed black.

My weather changing is done in the Weather class with cases.

Most tutorials I watched said to keep variables private when possible to prevent problems later on. So in the screenRGB class I have set up functions to set and get the RGB colours.

I think this is possibly where my errors are coming from.

When I run the program, I made it cout what the float values I was using were.

```
cout << screenrgb.getScreenRed() << endl;
```

this helped isolate a little where things where going wrong. The returned float values were  -1.07374e+008. Which seemed very strange

And only when I changed

```
float getScreenBlue(void){return screenBlue;}
```

to...

```
float getScreenBlue(void){return 1.0;}
```

... did the colour change when the window opened, and understandably this worked. This makes me beleive that the set functions are incorrectly coded.

I feel that I may have just missed one small thing, or possibly a massive thing. From my understanding the rest seems to work.

This is my full code sorry if this chunk is too large to understand, I can try and remove parts I know are not the problem if need be.

http://pastebin.com/1NhHkSN1

Thanks again, and apologies if this has been posted incorrectly.

Ben.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `init()` function, you declare a local instance of screenRGB:

```
void init(void)
{
    screenRGB screenrgb;    /// <-- local instance!

    cout << screenrgb.getScreenRed() << endl;

    glClearColor(screenrgb.getScreenRed(), screenrgb.getScreenGreen(), screenrgb.getScreenBlue(), 1.0);
    cout << screenrgb.getScreenRed() << endl;

    glShadeModel(GL_SMOOTH);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
}
```

This instance is separate from the one you declared in `Weather::changeWeather()`:

```
    string changeWeather()
    {
            screenRGB screenrgb;  /// <-- A completely different local instance!
```

Those two instances are *unconnected*, since each is local to its own function.  Furthermore, you get a completely new local instance every time you call that function.

You need to pass a single common instance around, possibly as `screenRGB &`, or similar, depending on what exactly you're trying to do overall.  Declare that instance in some outer scope that calls both `Weather::changeWeather()` as well as your rendering code.